# block non full requests with nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a tube website like YouTube and some android applications keep steeling the videos temporary links like :

> https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4?Key=HUi_kuAjHyUHVGccqoYCAA&Expires=1578620165

and they using it with their own player which causing me a high bandwidth usage.

The IP address cannot be blocked because its the user IP not the application itself and there is no way to tell if its my user or the application user , also I've tried to block based on user agent + referrer but they faked it ,

due to nature of the application it only need to get the video direct link from the page itself and it doesn't get all the page resources so i want to try blocking non full requests of that page. If someone requests only a piece of that page then it must be blocked, but if the request is for the full page then it should be allowed.

Comment: When you say your website "contains some links", what exactly do you mean? Do you mean hyperlinks to other websites, resources stored on your server such as images or files to download, or something else? Please edit your question to clarify the problem you're trying to solve, as it's ambiguous as written. If you want to stop people using your images in their pages you can use hotlink prevention (google it). Otherwise if something is on the public internet and doesn't require authentication / authorisation, in practice anyone can access it however they want.

Comment: I have edited the post to explain it more !

Comment: You will need to authenticate your users and authorise the requests they make. I don't think you can do that just with Nginx, you'll probably need to write some code or make use of a service to help you with that.

Comment: Plus you should consider that some of those elements that form part of a 'full page' would (should) be cachable, and thus wouldn't be requested by a legitimate client.

Comment: Add some code to set a cookie, then have nginx check for that cookie when trying to gain access to the video link. Change it a couple of times a day with a cron job. That is a fairly low tech option but it should work

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy easy to do this in the basic server configuration. The other party will always be able to spoof their requests to bypass any blocking or rate limiting controls.

The only way to do it without authentication would be to use the Nginx Key Value store.

In this scenario, the initial request to the static HTML page would create a key:value pair, based on a hash of the request parameters (e.g. agent, referrer, ip address).

Any subsequent request for the media asset would then have to confirm that a key for that hash exists before serving the asset.

Technically, this could also be spoofed, but would involve a lot more work for the other person.

You probably have to write a few lines of lua code to incorporate into Nginx to tie it together.

Comment: And do you have any example ?